# MySQL update, but delete on duplicate key (due to unique index)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, unique-constraint

I'm looking for some insight in regards to updating several rows in a database table that would, in turn, violate a unique index of the table.  For some context:

I have a many-to-many join table that defines a relationship between two other tables.  There's a unique index on this table that says that the child table foreign keys must be unique to a single parent table. For example:

```
=============================
| ID | Parent ID | Child ID |
-----------------------------
|  1 |         1 |        1 |
|  1 |         1 |        2 |
|  1 |         1 |        3 |
|  1 |         2 |        1 |
|  1 |         2 |        2 |
|  1 |         3 |        1 |
=============================
```

I have a requirement to deprecate some of the allowable `Child ID` values and map those, now deprecated IDs, to their non-deprecated values.  (e.g: in the above example, if we deprecate `3` => `2`, it would cause a unique index violation because there is already a relationship between `Parent 1` and `Child 2`)

Question:
Is there a way to handle the unique index violations and just simply delete the current row being updated?

I know there's an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause in MySQL, but is there an `UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY DELETE`?.  I think we could even accept deleting the row that's causing the unique index, before performing the update. (e.g: Something like `UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY DELETE EXISTING ROW`)

Just trying to avoid a super complex SQL migration that's more prone to errors if I can.

Thanks for any help or tips, let me know if you need more information and I will provide as much as I'm allowed to.

---

**Update:** Thanks to Bill's answer I was able to come up with this SQL procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `migrate_deprecated_children`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;

    -- Insert new items, ignoring any that already exist
    INSERT IGNORE INTO JOIN_TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID)
        SELECT PARENT_ID,
           (CASE
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 106 THEN 68
                WHEN CHILD_ID IN (109, 111, 124, 131) THEN 110
                WHEN CHILD_ID IN (113, 114) THEN 61
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 115 THEN 48
                WHEN CHILD_ID IN (118, 143, 169, 77, 86) THEN 3
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 121 THEN -1
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 127 THEN 102
                WHEN CHILD_ID IN (134, 80) THEN 173
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 136 THEN 50
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 145 THEN 56
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 146 THEN 0
                WHEN CHILD_ID IN (14, 15) THEN 37
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 54 THEN 94
                WHEN CHILD_ID IN (84, 99) THEN 13
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 87 THEN 83
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 91 THEN 96
                WHEN CHILD_ID = 98 THEN 30
                ELSE CHILD_ID
               END) as CHILD_ID
           FROM JOIN_TABLE;

    -- Delete all deprecated rows
    DELETE FROM JOIN_TABLE WHERE CHILD_ID IN (14,15,54,77,80,84,86,87,91,98,99,106,109,111,113,114,115,118,121,124,127,131,134,136,143,145,146,169);

    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible in MySQL. You will need to run two separate statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single SQL statement supported by MySQL that does what you describe.

The simplest solution is this two-step process:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO m2mtable (id, parent_id, child_id)
 SELECT id, parent_id, 2
 WHERE child_id = 3;

DELETE FROM m2mtable WHERE child_id = 3;
```

You should do both statements wrapped in a transaction so the change appears to be atomic to any other client.

*Not every task must be done in a single SQL statement.*

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mean to imply that it *had* to be one statement.  My original plan was to use a procedure and define an error handler, updating each row individually, in a transaction, of course.  Thanks for the advice.

Just to make sure I'm on the same page, this will: 1. Attempt to insert the new association with the new child id, unless it conflicts already.  2. Then delete the, now invalid, associations???

Very simple and elegant solution!!  I'll review it with my peers and mark as correct.  (It looks legit thought :))

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You don't have to do it row-by-row. You can insert a _set_ of rows based on the result set of the SELECT above. The `INSERT IGNORE` means rows that have conflicts are ignored instead of invalidating the whole INSERT. Which is exactly what you want in this case.